# Does Clang profile guided optimization work for android apps

Tags: android, performance, android-developer-api, clang-static-analyzer, pgo

Does Clang profile guided optimization work for Android apps having native libraries? I followed the steps given here, I was able to instrument the native libraries, but no .profraw files got generated when I ran my app.

[Link](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/pgo)